# Android exoplayer gives media codec exception

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

On one of the android devices exoplayer video does not work and gives below exception

`com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.realtek.video.decoder, Format(1, null, video/avc, -1, null, [1280, 720, -1.0], [-1, -1])`

`Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.realtek.video.decoder, error 0xfffffff`

Do let know if you have idea how this can be solved

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this issue is not releasing and reinitialising the player each time when playing more than one video.

It should probably fail more gracefully but it seems that this is a known behaviour.